# How do i check if cache is working on aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I check if cacheControl is working on aws s3 file upload?

```
            'CacheControl' => 'max-age=2592000',
```

Comment: Request the file and check for the CacheControl header in the response, I'm assuming you already are accessing your s3 objects so this should be just validating headers on the existing requests you are making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Chrome, go to inspect element and keep the network tab open. Then request the file in browser using the http url. You will be able to see whether you get it from the server or cache looking at the size column. It will show as (from memory cache), (from disk cache) or the file size if its received from server. Also you can observe 'Not modified' when its received from a cache.

Comment: Yes, its not Not Modified.
    Status Code:304 Not Modified